# Getting today date in this format Sat Aug 22 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0400

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I get today's date in this format

```
Mon Aug 22 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0400
```

Comment: Your day is wrong too. Must be Mon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use custom datetime format strings, described [in MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
string inputDate = "Mon Aug 22 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0400";

DateTime createdDate = DateTime.ParseExact(inputDate,
                "ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'zzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Console.WriteLine(createdDate);
```